# using a editText as a search box

Tags: android, search, android-listview, android-edittext

I have a search icon, an invisible editeText and a ListView.
ListView contains some items.
Now, when I click the search image, the editText appears and then the text is entered. Suppose on item from the ListView appears and **on clicking the item, a dialogue box appears.**
I am unable to perform the last part. I think it can be done using a vector.
Please can anyone give me the solution.
Following is the code for your reference:

```
Spinner citySipinner;
EditText searchCity;
TextView header;
ImageView viewText;
ListView dealersList;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    String city[] = {"Select city...", "A", "B"};

    String dealers[] = {"XYZ", "CDE"};


    viewText = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    header = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textHeader);
    dealersList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    searchCity = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, dealers);
    dealersList.setAdapter(adapter);

    viewText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (searchCity.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
                 // showing the EditText
                searchCity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                searchCity.requestFocus();
                header.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                //Request Focus on EditText
             } else{
                 searchCity.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                 header.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }
    });

    searchCity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
           // When user changed the Text
           HomeActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
       }

       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
               int arg3) {


       }

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

       }
   });



}
```

}

Comment: whats there in `setOnItemClickListener` you have implemented to your activity? can you show that code.

Comment: android:imeOptions="actionSearch" in edittext layout

Answer (score 0):

You should use `getChildAt()` for the `ListView` and when you get that as a view, you can put an `onClickListener` to it, as below:

```
dealersList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int pos,
                long arg3) {
            //the things you wanna to
            // you can just get the position and everything and make a switch-case statement
        }
    });
```

So in that the things you wanna do part, you want to pop a dialog box. Create a class and add it to the `Manifest` file of the project similar to below, mentioning that it's a dialog.

```
<activity
        android:name=".Dialog"
        android:label="@string/dialog"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >//this part is important to show that it's a dialog
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.app.DIALOG" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

and now in that "the things you wanna to" part you can create an intent to this new activity and see it as a dialog like below:

```
Intent dealerIntent = new Intent(Main.this, DIALOG.class);
                startActivity(dealerIntent);
```

Comment: Edited the answer, see above.

Answer (score 0):

```
dealersList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

change this to....

```
dealersList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long arg3) 
        {
            //the logic you need to implement
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

it might be helpful

editTextPassword.addTextChangedListener(mTextEditorWatcher);

```
            }


            // EditTextWacther  Implementation

            private final TextWatcher  mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
                {
                            // When No Password Entered
                           textViewPasswordStrengthIndiactor.setText("Not Entered");
                }

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
                {

                }

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
                {
                             if(s.length()==0)
                                    textViewPasswordStrengthIndiactor.setText("Not Entered");
                             else if(s.length()<6)
                                    textViewPasswordStrengthIndiactor.setText("EASY");
                             else if(s.length()<10)
                                    textViewPasswordStrengthIndiactor.setText("MEDIUM");
                             else if(s.length()<15)
                                    textViewPasswordStrengthIndiactor.setText("STRONG");
                               else
                                    textViewPasswordStrengthIndiactor.setText("STRONGEST");

                           if(s.length()==20)
                               textViewPasswordStrengthIndiactor.setText("Password Max Length Reached");
                }
        };
```